# A measure having no point masses.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, terminology

What does it mean for a measure to have no point masses? Is this sort if like saying that individual points have measure zero?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. A measure has no point masses if for every point, there is a measurable subset containing it that has measure zero. The difference plays only a role when not all singletons are in the underlying $\sigma$-algebra.